# Comprehensive List of Product APIs

Tags: .net, web-services, api, directory

Does anyone know of a site giving a comprehensive list of APIs for retrieving lists of product data (e.g. books, films, games, wines, beers, etc)?  Is there a directory for web APIs out there somewhere?

Comment: http://www.programmableweb.com/ ?

Comment: ps. WikiData looks like it may be a useful resource for this in future: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Introduction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with ApiHub: http://www.apihub.com/

For example, for APIs related to books, you can search: http://www.apihub.com/search/api/books

Comment: Great site; thanks Diego